# AdvRef pin setup

Tags: microcontroller, adc, voltage-reference, cortex-m4

I have an MCU Cortex M4 that don't have any internal voltage reference but only external. I need to setup a reference on ADVREF pin.

I found different schematics used:

**Ex. 1:**

[image]

**Ex. 2:**

[image]

**Ex. 3:**

[image]

**Datasheet Details:**

[image]

My questions are:

- Can you explain me difference in this 3 example?
- In ex.3, if I apply a 3.3v to LM4040 with a 2.2k Resistor, I'll still have 3.0v?
- Since circuit will work in an environment with EMIs(I don't know which freq. may affect an ADVREF) and I need a small factor/minimal components, which one do you advice me? Or can you advice me another method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Example 1 does not properly show any voltage source as Vref - it can come from ADVREF or VDD_MAIN
- Example 2 has a potential divider (R307 and R306) forming a voltage that is buffered by the OP-AMP. This uses a voltage reference chip (a 4.096 shunt regulator) across the potential divider to keep things fairly stable if the power rail (VCC_P5V0) moves around.
- Example 3 uses a 3V reference (or 3.3V aka VCC33) directly connectable to the VREF pin.

Example 1 should be ignored and you should concentrate on 2 and 3.

Example 3 is the most stable when linked to the voltage reference. Example 2 will be less stable because it uses a potential divider and an op-amp and these add errors to the voltage produced from the reference.

> In ex.3, if I apply a 3.3v to LM4040 with a 2.2k Resistor, I'll still
>   have 3.0v?

This is because it is a shunt regulator i.e. it works like a zener diode (read the device data sheet)

Comment: I have another question, in ex.3, if I want to use 3.3V as reference it's more stable to connect it directly to VREF from 3v3 voltage regulator or should I use an LM4040-3.3?

Comment: If your ADC measurments are ratiometric (i.e. the 3V3 supply scales the input signals proportionally as in a something like a thermistor or RTC) then its better (lower errors) to use that 3V3 source. If not use a voltage reference if measurement stability and accuracy is important to you.